# Excel Pivot Tables, Calculating a Percentage of Total Values for filtered values

Tags: excel

I have a table (below) and I would like to display the percentage in the column "Count of Value" I can do this but however if I filter the results the percentage applied is only to the filtered data. In here instead of getting what I need which is the percentage of won leads by month (Jan 50% and Feb 75%) I get the percentage based on the total won leads (5, which were 3 in Feb and 3 in Jan 60/40).

I'm not good with Excel at all, I'm trying to help the sales manager with this for 2 days and I can't calculate the totals. I've learned a bit about Excel but I can't figure out how to do this without doing it manually which will be a big pain in the backside.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[image: Excel Table and Pivot Table]

[image: Leads Percentage]

Comment: Look for DAX. You'd have to add the table to the data model and then calculate a measure.

Comment: I've had a quick look at DAX but I still don't know how I can make it work.

Comment: What Excel version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get it done in Excel 2016+ (screenshots are in spanish, but serve as a guide).

Based on this setup:

[image]

Steps:

1) Convert your data to an Excel [structured table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664)

- Select the data range
- Click Home | Format as Table | mark (Use headers)

[image]

2) Add table to Power Query
- With table selected, click [Data | From table or range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-the-query-editor-power-query-1d6cdb63-bf70-4ae8-a7d5-6ae9547004d9)

3) Adjust data types for each column
- Click on the icon in the columns headers and select the appropiate data type
- In this case, make sure Date table is set to the date type

[image]

4) Click Close and Load (the option that expands) and select Close and load to

[image]

5) Select "Connection only" and check the "Add to data model" checkbox (and click ok)

[image]

6) Click on Data | Manage data model

[image]

7) On the table (which should be called Table1 if you didn't rename it) select the first cell of the grid below the data

[image]

8) Add the following text to the formula bar and click enter

```
Percentage won by month:=COUNTROWS(Tabla1) / CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Tabla1);all(Tabla1[Lead stage]))
```

[image]

9) Close the windows and go back to Excel

10) In a new blank sheet click Insert | Pivot Table

[image]

11) Make sure Use Data Model is selected and click Ok

[image]

12) Add the fields to the pivot table, making sure the measure you added "Percentage won by month" is in the values section

[image]